# What is default for PointInTimeRecoveryEnabled in AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, backup, point-in-time-recovery

I checked [AWSCloudFormation dynamodb documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-dynamodb-table-pointintimerecoveryspecification.html) and since PointInTimeRecoveryEnabled is optional, what would be the default value if it is not provided?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is false but I do not have documentation